# Values not yet registered at load up

Tags: ios, ios7, appdelegate

I am currently doing the following: I check the value of my NSInteger that I'm using as a flag using this method in my app delegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"Application did become active");
    TCAViewController *uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init];
    if(uiTCA.failed == 1){
    [uiTCA restart]; // this method in my view controller will trigger my viewDidLoad
     }
}
```

But at this point the failed variable is 0 even if failed was set to 1 before the app went to background. Once the app is fully loaded I then have the value of 1 for my failed integer. But obviously at this point its too late. How do I fix this problem. I currently just have NSInteger declared globally.

```
@interface TCAViewController () {

    NSInteger failed;

}
```

Here is my entire appDelegate.m

```
#import "TCAAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TCAAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [myApp sharedInstance];

    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    NSError *activationError = nil;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"Application did become active");

    if(!uiTCA)
    {
        uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if(uiTCA.failed == 1){
        [uiTCA restart]; // this method in my view controller will trigger my viewDidLoad
    }


    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

And this is my appDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myApp.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "TCAViewController.h"

@interface TCAAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

    TCAViewController *uiTCA;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: code TCAViewController *uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init]; creates a new instance, so it will have default values.the old instance is no longer available.

Comment: I can't see where you are setting your initial viewController.  It must be storyboard or nib that I'm unfamiliar with.  In that case you are going to have to get the handle of your current `window.rootViewController` and check the failed against that (assuming that it's of type `TCAViewController`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was creating a new instance it will take the default value of that integer(zero)
so instead in my TCAViewController.m I just added an observer for that delegate method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(restart) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
TCAViewController *uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init];
```

Creates a new object.  This new object will have all class variables initialized as new.  So your failedFlag will be 0.  You are going to have to make a reference to a `TCAViewController` in your appDelegate.h.  If you create that object you will be able to re-use it later in your appDidBecomeActive and it will have your previously set value for failed.

Edit with code example:

In your AppDelegate.h you are going to want something like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate
{
    TCAViewController *uiTCA;
}
```

And in your .m something like (actually where ever you create the first instance of your `TCAViewController`):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(@"Application did become active");
    if(!uiTCA)
    {
        uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if(uiTCA.failed == 1){
        [uiTCA restart]; // this method in my view controller will trigger my viewDidLoad
     }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work? I still get zero at that point. This is how I now have failed declared in my TCAViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger failed;

Comment: Then you need to post your code for the entire AppDelegate.m.  You are not creating your initial view controller properly and I can't tell you where it's wrong until I see what you are doing.

Comment: all the code you gave me is the only thing in my app delegate.m but I just posted the delegate implementation and header files